# How to "debug" a DVR8824 stepper driver board?

Tags: stepper-motor, debugging, stepper-driver

I am trying to control a stepper motor following a [description](https://makersportal.com/blog/raspberry-pi-stepper-motor-control-with-nema-17). I have the exact same elements.

[image]

I do not have any tension on the down-right pins (they are supposed to be 5V and power the RPi).

I measure 12V on the green connector, and `VMOT`-`GND` below

[image]

*([source](https://www.pololu.com/product/2133))*

I already tried two boards and two DVR8824 chips, same result.

This is such a simple setup that I honestly cannot imagine what could have gone wrong - how do I "debug" such a circuit?

Comment: May I ask what the result is at all? I think /ENABLE should be connected to GND

Comment: @Jens: well the result is that the RPi does not boot (since there is no power on the +5V pin). It does if I power it via the USB port but in that case I guess that its `GND` would be missing on the board and the GPIO could not work (I am wildly guessing, having partied during my electronics courses, something I am really unhappy about 30 years later)

Comment: The driver module will and can not provide a supply for the RaspBerry, you must feed it via USB or separate 5V supply.

Comment: @Jens oh THANK YOU! it worked now. I was sure that since there was 12V available, the connection to the +5V on the Rpi would be to power it. If iy could turn your comment into a short answer I would be glad to accept it. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The driver module will and can not provide a supply for the Raspberry, you must feed it via USB or separate 5V supply.
All other connections look good.
Remember the /ENABLE input is active low.